# how to post image from our application to linkedin post ? in c# Or in javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, oauth.io

I am working on an asp.net MVC project and need to post image from application to LinkedIn.

Comment: please add more details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831292/when-i-use-this-code-in-local-then-it-work-fine-but-when-i-publish-it-on-iis-the